# Gradle Build fails after importing modules into Android project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, multi-module, agora.io

I am trying to import the `Agora.IO` modules from [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/blob/master/Android/APIExample/app/src/main/java/io/agora/api/example/examples/advanced/PushExternalVideo.java) to implement a screen sharing functionality. After cloning the repository at the provided link and adding it as a `Module` for my project, I am able to get all the `imports` correctly. The only imports that I needed were `import io.agora.api.*`, but the build fails with the following message.

```
Execution failed for task ':lib-switch-external-video:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lib-switch-external-video:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.4.2.
 Required by:
     project :lib-switch-external-video > project :lib-component

Possible solution:
- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

> This is how my project strucure looks after importing the modules:

[image]

Though I'm not much experienced with `multi-module` apps yet, but I have added these to my `settings.gradle` file already:

> settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = "dummy"
include ':app'
include ':lib-push-externalvideo'
include ':lib-screensharing'
include ':lib-player-helper'
include ':lib-stream-encrypt'
include ':lib-component'
include ':lib-raw-data'
include ':lib-switch-external-video'
```

inside the default `build.gradle` of `lib-component` module I found

```
api 'com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.4.2'
api 'io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4'
```

Inside the `build.gradle` of each of these modules there is already either of these added:

```
implementation project(path: ':lib-component')
or
api project(path: ':lib-component')
```

The only reason why I chose importing those modules is because I wasn't able to find the `gradle` dependency that had support for these imports. If there is such a dependency, please let me know about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly mentioned in the message. Gradle cannot resolve `com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.4.2` dependency in any of the repositories that were added in the module.

Did you have jitpack repo defined there?

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    
    // Other repositories you need
}
```

Also, separate from your issue, your settings.gradle file seems a bit different. I assume that you've copied all the source code into your project.

Instead, I'd choose to link them instead of copying the sources in this case. For that, you can use

```
include ':lib-component'
project(':lib-component').projectDir = new File('/path/to/cloned/repo/lib-component/')
```

Prefer this when you're debugging a library which you appear to be. This way, you add that exact module in this build, and making any changes here will actually happen in that project. Allows you to simply commit or change branches in that repo.

Comment: Harsha I did not have the jitpack earlier, but even after adding it to the `project level  build.gradle` file there seems to be another error: `lib-switch-external-video\src\main\java\io\agora\advancedvideo\externvideosource\ExternalVideoInputManager.java:230:`
 error: cannot find symbol
            ENGINE.setVideoSource(ExternalVideoInputManager.this);
                  ^
  symbol:   method setVideoSource(ExternalVideoInputManager)
  location: variable ENGINE of type RtcEngine

Comment: This file at the specified location is imported from the module and not created by me.

Comment: Now, that's a separate issue. Try to see where that symbol is coming from. Is it some sort of extension method defined in any other modules that you haven't included in your build?

Comment: I'd try to see if the original example project builds fine first. If yes, then proceed to linking modules.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding module the other way also but it appeared to have the same effect for me, it seems adding `jitpack` and using imports from `io.agora.rtc` instead of `io.agora.rtc2` fixed this build error for me :)

Comment: this doesn't work on latest android studio... shows a message "Cannot resolve symbol 'File'"

Comment: I have also imported the using the path you've mentioned. But since I also release the library I have a file `gradle-mvn-push.gradle` inside library project. And I am using `apply from: "$rootDir/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"` inside `build.gradle` module of library project. And while importing its giving me this error on the project.

    A problem occurred evaluating project ':ecg'.
    > Could not read script '/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/AndroidStudioProjects/PersonalProjects/SDKTest/gradle-mvn-push.gradle' as it does not exist. Its taking the new project path.